# Combining two dataframes with different rows, keeping contents of first dataframe on all rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good day All,

I have two data frames that needs to be merged which is a little different to the ones I found so far and could not get it working. What I am currently getting, which I am sure is to do with the index, as dataframe 1 only has 1 record. I need to copy the contents of dataframe one into new columns of dataframe 2 for all rows.
[Current problem highlighted in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixhxN.png)

I have tried merge, append, reset index etc...

DF 1:
[Dataframe 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4E15.png)

DF 2:
[Dataframe 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSygA.png)

Output Requirement:
[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPDhn.png)

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Update:
I got it to work using the below statements, is there a more dynamic way than specifying the column names?

mod_df['Type'] = mod_df['Type'].fillna(method="ffill")

mod_df['Date'] = mod_df['Date'].fillna(method="ffill")

mod_df['Version'] = mod_df['Version'].fillna(method="ffill")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a single row in df1, use a cross `merge`:

```
out = df2.merge(df1, how='cross')
```